# Webview sometimes displays blank page

Tags: java, android

I am currently Working on a `webview` in android.
The code runs perfectly and displays the site perfectly.
But after using it for 5 to 6 times (or randomly) my `ProgressBar` shows 100% 
but the `webview` shows the blank white page.

And after deleting the whole data of the app it again works fine.
and deleting cache doesn't work.

Pardon me for any mistake I am very new to programming and StackOverflow.

I tried almost every solution I found on StackOverflow but didn't work the difference between others and my situation is that my code runs perfectly but after the random number of usage it goes blank.

```
  @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
private void loadTheUrlForMe() {
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    returnShared();
    webView.setWebViewClient(new Myclass());
    Toast.makeText(this,url,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}

class Myclass extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view,url);
    }
}
```

**MY LAYOUT**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"/>
    <WebView
        android:layout_below="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="600dp">
    </WebView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

It shows a pure blank white page and nothing else

Comment: How much time it stay blank?

Comment: it just stays blank and the progress bar shows 100 almost instantly.The progress bar is totally correct as it works fine normally.